# How can I increase priority of Jobs submitted ( to reduce queue time ) on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ai

On Google Cloud, I submit lots of Jobs which gets queued; and sometimes it takes really long for those jobs to start. Can I specify priority of critical jobs so that they start immediately or at higher priority.

One of the command I am using is

```
$ gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOBNAME \
  --module-name=trainer.task \
  --package-path=$(pwd)/ \
  --job-dir=$OUTPUT_DIR \
  --staging-bucket=gs://$BUCKET \
  --region=$REGION \
  --scale-tier=STANDARD_1 \
  --output_dir=$OUTPUT_DIR \
  --traindata $DATA_DIR/train* --evaldata $DATA_DIR/test*
```

Comment: Some thoughts and hope this may be helpful: You can use Cloud Scheduler to schedule the jobs during different hours of the day. You may also consider to use Composer for that. Also, you can use another project in GCP to launch part of the jobs with high priority there.

Comment: On the other hand, if the jobs are queued because lack of resources, you can always request a [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/quotas) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that no, there isn't a parameter that you can specify in order to give higher or lower priority to jobs you run. [These](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training) are all the available ones.

Enle is right, you can either use Cloud [Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) or Cloud [Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) by passing unique job Id's. Or make a different GCP Project and run the jobs that are more urgent to you there.

Let us know.